# When requiring a file, the way the path is written affects the availability of WordPress functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the `WPAlchemy` class in my WordPress theme and I have moved it into the theme folder (the author instructs users to place it in the content directory, but I would like it in the theme folder).

Everything works as expected when I include the file this way:

```
require_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/efs/inc/metaboxes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php';
```

but if I change the statement to:

```
require_once get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/metaboxes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php';
```

The file loads fine, but throws an *"undefined function"* error on `add_action()` in the file `MetaBox.php`.

Why does the way I write the URL affect the availability of WordPress functions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but i would just print both paths with an echo statement:

```
echo WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/efs/inc/metaboxes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php';

echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/metaboxes/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php';
```

I'm sure that both strings are different.

Comment: "I don't know the answer" typically means you shouldn't be posting an answer. As is, this post is better suited as a comment.

Comment: The difference is that the second one is a URI -- it starts with "http://" and the first one is relative to the home directory.  Why does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you use require_once on a uri/url then you need to have the php.ini setting of

```
; Whether to allow include/require to open 
; URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; @SEE http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = On
```

by default it is off ( for good reason )